# GWBASIC programming language with total size of 79KB only How?

Tags: gw-basic

A programming Language only 79kb in size.

GWBASIC programming language confuse me, i download it and its size is only **79KB** only how this is possible? i never seen a language with **79kb** of size before.

Other programming language like mysql its size is **32.6M** in setup.

Please exaplain whay GWBASIC is **79KB** in size.

Thanks

Comment: 79KB small? Check out [Brainf**k](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/bf/) it's about 240 bytes! Then there is [Turbo Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal) coming in at 39K and that includes the IDE!

Comment: Kkrieger was not created in gwbasic I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A BASIC interpreter of the early desktop PC era like [GW-BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gwbasic) is a language interpreter, and not much more than that.  Libraries (for graphics or networking or database, for example) are not provided.
The "IDE" is a simple line-oriented source code editor, and hence very small.  Documentation and instruction guides are hard copy only.  There are no external tools (config management, unit testing) that need to be integrated.

Why such a feature-poor environment?  Developers are constrained by main memory limitations (hence how big an executable can be) and distribution media of small capacity (floppy discs, cassettes, etc.).

Comment: Not libraries but integrated: GW-BASIC has support for graphics and serial communication which may count as a form of networking.